# Remove modal footer from twitter bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove the footer from my modal. But it is only removing the contents and not the space acquired by it.

Here is my code...

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times; </button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use '`<div class="modal-footer">`' in your modal template then bootstrap will made it for you. I think this is why you see the footer with your code. 
My solution is hidding the footer in the template (last line) :

```
<div class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;       </button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="display:none"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`<div class="modal-footer" hidden="true"></div>`

Comment: Can you explain this solution to tell the original poster why this will solve their problem please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the "extra space" is the `<p>` margin. Try this css :

```
.modal .modal-body p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the padding given to `modal-footer` class. Try overriding it

```
.modal .modal-footer {
    padding: 4px;
}
```

I have kept it as `4px` to preserve round corners

Comment: Can u post a screenshot of it? It unlikely that its not shrinking the parent height even after removing the footer. unless you have specified fixed height somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can override modal-header, modal-footer of the bootstrap modal.

Add the following code.

```
 .modal-footer{display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achievable using jQuery

```
require(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
],
function(
    $,
    modal
) {

    var options = {
        type: 'popup',
        responsive: true,
        innerScroll: true,
        buttons: []
    };

    $('#approvalsModal').modal(options,{
        closed: function(){
           // Do some action when modal closed
        }
    });

    $(".approvalsModal").click(function(){
        $("#approvalsModal").modal('openModal');    
    });

    }
);
```